# Espaçamento na imagem com HTML5

Tags: html5

Quando eu coloco uma imagem ela vem automaticamente com um espaçamento em cima e embaixo da imagem de aproximadamente 5px, gostaria de saber como remover esse espaçamento já tentei colocar border: 0px e margin: 0px e não resolveu.

```
<figure>
  <figcaption>Curso HTML5</figcaption>
    <img src="imagens/html5.png" alt="Imagem do html5" title="Curso html5"> 
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

Essas margens são adicionadas pelo navegador, dependendo do mesmo. Por exemplo o Google Chrome adiciona:

```
figure {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 40px;
}
```

Para remover esta margem, basta adicionares:

```
figure {
    margin: 0;
}
```

> Vê os exemplos abaixo, com e sem a margem removida:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/uepswk2q
>   http://jsfiddle.net/uepswk2q/1/

Comment: Então eu fiz isso e não resolveu continuou com a margem em cima e em baixo mais consegui resolver desse jeito...

figure {
    width: 960px;
    height: 498px;
    margin: 0;
}
Ai sumiu as margens, Obrigado!